# javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException when trying to compile application

Tags: java, sslhandshakeexception

My java application had been worning fine until I tried compiling it again and I got this error:

```
build.xml:246: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1914)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:279)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:273)
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1477)
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:213)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:961)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:897)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1033)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1342)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1369)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1353)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:153)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Get$GetThread.openConnection(Get.java:690)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Get$GetThread.openConnection(Get.java:715)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Get$GetThread.get(Get.java:606)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Get$GetThread.run(Get.java:596)
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:385)
at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:292)
at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260)
at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:326)
at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:231)
at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:126)
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1459)
... 14 more
 Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:196)
at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:268)
at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:380)
... 20 more
```

I was recompiling it because I had made a change but once I got this error I took the change out and still get this.

Does anybody know what might be causing it or what may have suddenly changed on my server?

Comment: [Does this help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9619478/1790644)?

Comment: Thanks Matt. That did the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below solution for bypass certification when you call Https api

1) Write HttpsTrustManager.java class

```
import java.security.KeyManagementException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;

import javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSession;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;

public class HttpsTrustManager implements X509TrustManager {

    private static TrustManager[] trustManagers;
    private static final X509Certificate[] _AcceptedIssuers = new X509Certificate[]{};

    @Override
    public void checkClientTrusted(
            java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] x509Certificates, String s)
            throws java.security.cert.CertificateException {

    }

    @Override
    public void checkServerTrusted(
            java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] x509Certificates, String s)
            throws java.security.cert.CertificateException {

    }

    public boolean isClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain) {
        return true;
    }

    public boolean isServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
        return _AcceptedIssuers;
    }

    public static void allowAllSSL() {
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {

            @Override
            public boolean verify(String arg0, SSLSession arg1) {
                return true;
            }

        });

        SSLContext context = null;
        if (trustManagers == null) {
            trustManagers = new TrustManager[]{new HttpsTrustManager()};
        }

        try {
            context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
            context.init(null, trustManagers, new SecureRandom());
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            //e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
            //e.printStackTrace();
        }

        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(context
                .getSocketFactory());
    }

}
```

2) Now call below function before call the api like bwlow

```
    public static void getServerData(final Context cntx) {
            myNotificationDb = new Notification_Db(cntx);
            RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(cntx);

            HttpsTrustManager.allowAllSSL();

            JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(
                    Request.Method.GET, "Url", null,
                    new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                             // Your response

                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        }

                    }) {
                @Override
                public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {

                    // Your header parameter if you have otherwise this is optional

                    return headers;
                }
            };



queue.add(jsObjRequest);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> **build.xml:246**: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

This means during the build the code **connects to a SSL server, but the server's certificate is not trusted by the client**. This is all information we have from the exception.

It doesn't say anything about reason.

Usually the server's certificate (or it's CA) is not in trusted (not in the configured or default truststore) or the server's hostname doesn't correspond with the certificate CN (I believe you'd get another exception, so I'd bet on the truststore).